# Glassfish4 cannot create singelton exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-4

I have a system consist of ear project and some related EJB and JSF projects. I was using glassfish3.1.2, the EJB projects were exported into EJB jar and added to the deployment assembly of the EAR project. Everything was ok until i tried to upgrade the application server into glassfish4. when i run the EAR project in glassfish 4 an error indicate that cannot **create singleton session bean** pop up from eclipse for every bean i have in the ejb jars . but if i add the EJB project instead of ejb jar to the deployment assembly of the EAR project the EAR will deploy normally.
so is there a problem of adding ejb .jar files to the deployment assembly of Ear projects in glassfish 4. note that my ear project run well in glassfish 3.1.2 but i need glassfish4 in order to use jpa 2.1 .

Comment: Does the EAR contains the deployment descriptor? Since Java EE 6, the deployment descriptor is optional.

Comment: yup, it is already contain application.xml